# How to determine that Task is in WaitSleepJoin state

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Class Thread has a nice status **WaitSleepJoin**

Is there any way so that I could determine that state while using Task class?

Comment: What for? Sounds like a odd request, perhaps you could post the problem you are trying to solve with this.

Comment: Tasks are NOT threads, essentially they are wrappers to functions. A Threadpool thread is used to execute multiple tasks, one at a time, but you can't get access to that thread outside the task itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Tasks do not have direct correlation to Threads. A task could be using multiple threads during its lifetime.
That being said you can check the status of a task with [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.status.aspx) property.

Comment: A `Task` that is created from delegate (using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` or `new Task()` and `Start()`) wll run only on one thread. Granted, the question doesn't specify that this is the case.

Comment: 100% agreed, there are ways of enforcing this.